# Why Junit throws java.lang.ClassCastException even if classes are compatible and works fine in java code

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I have class Car, and class Vehicle.
and  Car extends Vehicle.

When i am writing junit for below method it gives class cast exception.
On type casting line.

```
   void method(){
    // some code
    Car a = (Car)Vehicle;
    // some code
    }
```

it throws exception as 
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.abc.Vehicle cannot be cast to com.abc.Car

Comment: If A extends B, you cant write it.

Comment: Sure you don't have a different class with the same name in test source directories?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: We can't help on such input, just *guess*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upcasting is always a codesmell and should be avoided. Usually it is needed because the code design violated the *Tell, don't ask!* principle.

Just guessing:
In your case the "procution code" always passes instaces of class `A` so that it works. But your test obviously sets up a class `B` object (at some point you didn't show) which fails to be casted to `A`.

Comment: Just a guess, but probably correct. Nonetheless, a pretty bad question, but well, you make up for that.